# w3c validator not working --> SSL connect attempt failed

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

My website works well. I can see it properly in the browser, but then I get this error message if I want to run the W3C validator on it.

[image]

Before asking here I searched the high and lows of stackoverflow, and tried the solution of adding the header to my express server `res.set('Accept', 'text/plain');` or `router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Accept', "application/soap+xml");
    next();
});` but still cannot be validated

Seems to be related to the SSL certificate but I have tested the certificate using several websites like `https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html` but it seems that the certificate is correct.

Any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You server has both an IPv4 and IPv6 address. The SSL setup is only done for IPv4 though. This means any attempt to reach the system from an IPv6 capable client will fail. The W3C validator is likely IPv6 capable so it fails while SSL shopper seems to check only IPv4 and succeeds. See [this SSLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.dvicario.es) for more details, where both IPv4 and IPv6 are checked.

Comment: Wow! Super interesting, this makes a lot of sense Steffen. I went through SSL labs report too and never understood why it was failing of IPv6, but the on IPv4 works. You have given me a great clue! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Steffen Ullrich's advice I managed to solve the issue. Had to enable a IPV6 address and associate it to my AAAA DNS. Once doing that, I had to update my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file so now looks like this

```
Listen [::]:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen [::]:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen [::]:443
</IfModule>
```

And it works! Now https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dvicario.es properly shows the analysis to both IPV6 and IPV4 and the w3c validator https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dvicario.es%2F works like a charm!

Thanks a lot Steffen Ullrich for taking the time of helping me! Greatly appreciated :)